# How to Solve the below special series??

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, algorithms, linear-programming

We have been given with a sorted (in non-decreasing order) list of $N$ positive integers $$(A_1, A_2 , \ldots , A_n)$$ and another positive integer $X$ . We have to make all the list integers zero using the integer $X$. But there are some conditions to do so:

- Condition 1 : At one time we can only subtract $X$ to one integer in List ($A_i, i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$).
- Condition 2 : After every operation (of condition 1) all the integers of list gets doubled and also $X$ gets doubled.
- Condition 3 : If $X$ is larger than $A_i$ for some $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$ then the value of $X$ changes to $A_i$ and then subtraction takes place.

What to find : **We need to find the minimum operations to make all integers in list zero.**

***A sample to Understand Better :***

**List :** `1 2 3 4 5`

**X : `4`**

Here to find most optimal solution we will first make 4 into zero using X. `Operation cost = 1` 
Now every integer will be doubled hence new list will be 
`2 4 6 0 10, X = 8` 
`2 4 6 0 2, X = 8` (subtracting 10 - 8) `Operation cost = 2`
Again every thing gets doubled so new list is 
`4 8 12 0 4 , X = 16` 
`4 8 0 0 4, X = 12` (as 12 < 16, X becomes 12) `Operation cost = 3` 
Again every thing gets doubled so new list is 
`8 16 0 0 8, X = 24` 
`8 0 0 0 8, X = 16`  (as 16 < 24, X becomes 16) `Operation cost = 4` 
Again every thing gets doubled so new list is 
`16 0 0 0 16, X = 32` 
`16 0 0 0 0, X = 16`  (as 16 < 32, X becomes 16) `Operation cost = 5` 
Again every thing gets doubled so new list is 
`32 0 0 0 0, X = 32` 
`0 0 0 0 0, X = 32`  (as 32 <= 32, X becomes 32) `Operation cost = 6`

So, Finally in 6 operations we made the list zero.

Some More cases with Answers :

**List :** `10 20 30 40 50` 
**X : `1`**
**Answer : `9`**

**List :** `1 20 110` 
**X : `10`** 
**Answer : `6`**

***Constraints :***  `(1 <= Ai <= 1000000000) , (1 <= X <= 1000000000)`

**My approach**

- Let `a` be an integer in list and `x` is given to make `a` into zero.
- Now, there will a series formed after every operation as given below

  `(a-x) , (2(a-x) - 2x) , (2(2(a-x) - 2x) - 4x) , ..........` 
  `(a-x) , (2a - 4x) , (4a - 12x), (8a - 32x) , .....` 
  `(a-x) , 2(a-2x) , 4(a-3x) , 8(a-4x) , .......` 
  `an = (2^(n-1))(a-nx) | where an is nth term`

**So to make `An` zero** `A-nx = 0, A = n/x`

***I have figured out how to make any single integer zero with x but i cant figure out how to make the list zero with minimum operations, As I have to make a code for that also so what i need is a basic algorithm which can be used to solve this problem.***

***Can anyone help me with this ??*